# Building installer in a gitlab ci stage

Tags: gitlab, inno-setup, gitlab-ci

In gitlab ci, I manage to build a solution, then I need to build an installer. It fails with an unknown option error.

In the setup stage I get this error:

> Inno Setup 6 Command-Line Compiler
>
> Copyright (C) 1997-2020 Jordan Russell. All rights reserved.
>
> Portions Copyright (C) 2000-2020 Martijn Laan. All rights reserved.
>
> Portions Copyright (C) 2001-2004 Alex Yackimoff. All rights reserved.
>
> *Unknown option: -c*
>
> *Unknown option: -c*
>
> Inno Setup 6 Command-Line Compiler
>
> Copyright (C) 1997-2020 Jordan Russell. All rights reserved.
>
> Portions Copyright (C) 2000-2020 Martijn Laan. All rights reserved.
>
> Portions Copyright (C) 2001-2004 Alex Yackimoff. All rights reserved.
>
> **ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1**

Here is my .gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
stages:
 - build
 - setup

build:
 image: mono:latest
 stage: build
 script:
  - 'nuget restore'
  - 'MONO_IOMAP=case msbuild /t:Build /p:Configuration=Release;Platform="Any CPU"'
 artifacts:
  paths:
   - MyApp/bin/Release/
   - MyApp/Inno/
   
setup:
 image: amake/innosetup
 stage: setup
 script:
  - 'compil32 /cc "Path/To/MyAppSetup.iss"'
  #- 'iscc "Path/To/MyAppSetup.iss"'
```

- Am I using the right innosetup command (compil32)?
- Same error with iscc command
- I can't see where the *-c* option comes from
- Any idea of whate is going wrong?

Reference: [Inno Setup Help](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setupcmdline)

Comment: The output you have posted in from from `iscc`, not `compil32`. `iscc` indeed does not have any `-c` nor `/cc` switches. See also [Compile Inno Setup project through a batch file (.bat)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52391796/850848).

Comment: @MartinPrikryl `/cc`is given in Inno Setup Help. And I didn't set a `-c` option so I don't know where it comes from.

Comment: `/cc` is switch of `compil32`, not `iscc`.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I didn't specify `/cc`with `iscc`

Answer (score 1):

As I could not know where was the problem, I decided to use a docker image for innosetup:

There I need a *docker in docker* step with `dind` and a docker docker.

```
build:
  stage: build
  image: docker:18
  variables:
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  services:
    - docker:dind
  script:
    - docker run --rm -v "$PWD:/work" amake/innosetup /dMyAppVersion=$MY_VERSION_NO "Path/To/MyAppSetup.iss"
  artifacts:
    paths:  
      - Path/To/bin/MyApp-*-Setup.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to [overwrite the default entrypoint](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#override-the-entrypoint-of-an-image) to run your script properly:

```
setup:
 image:
   name: amake/innosetup
   entrypoint: [""]
 stage: setup
 script:
  - iscc "Path/To/MyAppSetup.iss"
```

I also had to use `iscc` instead of `compil32`, got that idea from the dockerfile